# Silverlight LOB application with Stored Procedures with multiple tables in results

Tags: silverlight, wcf, linq, stored-procedures, ria

I have been messing round with Silverlight for a couple of weeks now with both WCF and WCF Ria Services and i am still running into problems with it.
My aim is at developing a LOB application where i use Stored procedures to select, update, insert and delete off the back.  In previous examples on WCF i have seen people using linq with a table in their Data Context and selecting direct from the table which i cannot do.  I have also seen people calling stored procedures directly in a data context.  If i call a stored procedure directly this then causes problems when it comes to validation as i do not have an entity for my stored procedure and cannot throw exceptions on the set property as this is created by the designer and will get overwritten each time.

When using RIA services I have seen examples where people insert a table into their Entity Framework model and then mapping select/update/insert/delete stored procedures to this, which works fine if you are selecting from one table.  The problem i have is that i have a query that selects an address table joined to a country table lookup via an ID for a "Country Name" then i can no longer map it to a table entity.

Im not sure if i am missing some critical points here but any help would be appreciated or a link to a tutorial that can help.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know this is being unhelpful in the short-term: Don't use RIA Services.

Make a real backend using WCF (or whatever you like) and simply expose methods that do your CRUD at that point. That way, you end up with a backend that's usable in multiple scenarios where RIAS doesn't exist and you're able to easily perform whatever validation you like before the call to the DB is made.

It's likely going to be a lot easier than you're thinking too.